# Override td bgcolor="#xxxxxx" with CSS Hover?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Excuse my CSS ignorance here.

I'm trying to apply a background color to a row using the following css:

```
tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #F69;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

The HTML table has some inherent column colors like shown below. The CSS above will not change the color to `#F69` and keep the colors `#993300`. Is there a way to override this HTML cell coloring?

```css
 tbody tr:hover {
   background-color: #F69;
   border: thin solid black;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>11 lbs</th>
    <td></td>
    <td bgcolor="#993300">1</td>
    <td bgcolor="#993300">2</td>
    <td bgcolor="#993300">3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The td element is set the background color but you are trying to change the background of the row. Why is that? Although your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/dh3pud4m/

Comment: Your code is working fine as it is suppose to. You styling tr element. May be you want to target both tr and td element likie this   tbody tr:hover,td:hover

Comment: If you are trying to change the `background-color` of the entire row and it's children on hover, then you should see my **Live Demo** that I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to apply a background color to a **row** using the...

If I read your question correctly, *and considering that you have both* [`th`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) *and* [`td`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) *elements in your table*, it seems like you are trying to change the [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) of the row's child elements at the same time when hovering over the row.

If that's the case, then this is your solution:

```
tr:hover td,
tr:hover th {
  background-color: #F69;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

**All of the row cells will be highlighted on hover.**

Otherwise, if you are trying to change the [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) one cell at a time, I recommend Maddy's answer.

**[Try it Online!](https://jsfiddle.net/5enks1zk/9/)**

Comment: @David-DjBryant No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are want something like this-

```css
tr td:hover {
  background-color: #F69;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
<tr>
  <th colspan="5">11 lbs</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="20%" bgcolor="#993300"></td>
  <td width="20%" bgcolor="#993300"></td>
  <td width="20%" bgcolor="#993300"></td>
  <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I hope it will helps you.